# Python: Data set that has repeating IDs with different column values. How do I select only one Row for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, enums

I am trying to create a tally that alternates the Region by one row when the next ID is run. I am expecting one result per each ID.

Tried a few methods but nothing seems to be working and running short on ideas.

Data Set

| ID | Region |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | North |
| 1 | South |
| 1 | East |
| 1 | West |
| 2 | North |
| 2 | South |
| 2 | East |
| 2 | West |
| 3 | North |
| 3 | South |
| 3 | East |
| 3 | West |
| 4 | North |
| 4 | South |
| 4 | East |
| 4 | West |
| 5 | Northwest |
| 5 | South West |
| 6 | Northwest |
| 6 | South West |
| 7 | North |
| 7 | South |
| 7 | East |
| 7 | West |
| 8 | North |
| 8 | South |
| 8 | East |
| 8 | West |
| 9 | North |
| 9 | South |
| 9 | East |
| 9 | West |
| 9 | Northwest |
| 9 | South West |

Expected Output

| ID | Region |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | North |
| 2 | South |
| 3 | East |
| 4 | West |
| 5 | Northwest |
| 6 | South West |
| 7 | North |
| 8 | South |
| 9 | North |

Comment: Is the order important in the output? What should be the output if you had North in place of Northwest for ID 5?

Comment: order is more important than output. Output would be North.

Comment: So it's fine to have repeated values? Do my proposed approaches below work for you? If not, can you show a counterexample and the matching expected output?

Comment: I am surprised that none of the proposed solutions solves your problem. Try to meet what @mozway asked for.

Comment: @mozway Repeating values are fine. Both of your approaches did not work. I think the matrix was on the right track but I was getting a length error when running it for a small sample set. I'll updated the question with expected output

Comment: @ShellShock why East for the last value and not North?

Comment: See the proposed updated in the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @mozway it should be north for id 9.

Comment: But **why**? There is no clear logic. Why don't you pick "North" as well for ID3 then?

Comment: @Morzway Think of all the region values for each ID make up there own group. So ID 9 Would be grouped under ('North, 'South, 'East', 'West', 'Northwest', 'South West')

Comment: OK, it was far from obvious, but this is what I guessed in my very last update. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) both columns and keep the rows for which the ranks are equal:

```
out = df.loc[pd.factorize(df['Region'])[0] == pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0]]
```

Output:

```
    ID      Region
0    1       North
5    2       South
10   3        East
15   4        West
16   5   Northwest
19   6  South West
```

Other idea, what about using an intermediate rectangular matrix and take its diagonal?

```
import numpy as np

df2 = (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Region', values='Region')
         .reindex(index=df['ID'].unique(), columns=df['Region'].unique())
      )

out = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df2.index, 'Region': np.diag(df2)})
```

Output:

```
   ID      Region
0   1       North
1   2       South
2   3        East
3   4        West
4   5   Northwest
5   6  South West
```

Intermediate rectangular matrix:

```
Region  North  South  East  West  Northwest  South West
ID                                                     
1       North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
2       North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
3       North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
4       North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
5         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  Northwest  South West
6         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  Northwest  South West
```

##### updated example

There is no clear logic, so I can just assume here…

###### assuming you want the restart the diagonals

```
import numpy as np

df2 = (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Region', values='Region')
         .reindex(index=df['ID'].unique(), columns=df['Region'].unique())
      )

idx = np.arange(df2.shape[0])
out = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df2.index, 'Region': df2.to_numpy()[idx, idx%df2.shape[1]]})
```

Output:

```
   ID      Region
0   1       North
1   2       South
2   3        East
3   4        West
4   5   Northwest
5   6  South West
6   7       North
7   8       South
8   9        East
```

Intermediate `df2`, with selected values `**HIGHLIGHTED**`:

```
Region      North      South      East      West      Northwest      South West
ID                                                                             
1       **NORTH**      South      East      West            NaN             NaN
2           North  **SOUTH**      East      West            NaN             NaN
3           North      South  **EAST**      West            NaN             NaN
4           North      South      East  **WEST**            NaN             NaN
5             NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  **NORTHWEST**      South West
6             NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN      Northwest  **SOUTH WEST**
7       **NORTH**      South      East      West            NaN             NaN
8           North  **SOUTH**      East      West            NaN             NaN
9           North      South  **EAST**      West      Northwest      South West
```

###### assuming you want to restart when the successive groups are different:

```
import numpy as np

df2 = (df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Region', values='Region')
         .reindex(index=df['ID'].unique(), columns=df['Region'].unique())
      )

group = df2.ne(df2.shift()).where(df2.notna()).any(axis=1).cumsum()

out = (df2.groupby(group, group_keys=False)
          .apply(lambda g: pd.Series(np.diag(g.dropna(axis=1)), index=g.index))
          .reset_index(name='Region')
       )
```

Output:

```
   ID      Region
0   1       North
1   2       South
2   3        East
3   4        West
4   5   Northwest
5   6  South West
6   7       North
7   8       South
8   9       North
```

Intermediate `df2` with groups of successive identical rows:

```
Region    North  South  East  West  Northwest  South West
ID group                                                 
1  1      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
2  1      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
3  1      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
4  1      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN

5  2        NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  Northwest  South West
6  2        NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  Northwest  South West

7  3      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN
8  3      North  South  East  West        NaN         NaN

9  4      North  South  East  West  Northwest  South West
```

Comment: That was an awesome approach @mozway

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is petty close to working. With the assumption I want to start for successive groups. Running into an issue when I run out. If I have 5 ID's with two directions I'm getting a Value Error. Length of values(2) does not match length of index (5).

Comment: Got this working Thanks for all of your help! Your are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution

```py
unique_ids = df['ID'].unique()
res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Region'])

for i, id in enumerate(unique_ids):
    region = df[df['ID'] == id]['Region'].iloc[i % 4]
    res_df = pd.concat([res_df, pd.DataFrame({'ID': [id], 'Region': [region]})], 
                                                ignore_index=True)
print(res_df)
```

---

```
  ID      Region
0  1       North
1  2       South
2  3        East
3  4        West
4  5   Northwest
5  6  South West
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the method ".drop_duplicates" might solve your problem. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

I think you should use the "subset" parameter, as indicated in documentation of the above link.

Answer (score 0):

The unique region names can be collected into a set, then for each group (grouped by `ID`) the next available region is extracted:

```
def get_next_region(r_group, regions):
    for reg in r_group:
        if reg in regions:
            regions.remove(reg)
            break
    return reg

regions = set(df.Region.unique())  # unique regions
reg_df = df.groupby('ID')['Region'].apply(get_next_region, regions=regions.copy())\
    .reset_index(name="Region")

print(reg_df)
```

---

```
   ID      Region
0   1       North
1   2       South
2   3        East
3   4        West
4   5   Northwest
5   6  South West
```

Comment: Looks like it runs for most of the ID's but a few it returns null for the ID even though it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution. It does result in the desired output for the example you gave, but would not necessarily generalize to any combination of ID values or combinations of Regions. It may be useful if you are looking for pandas methods that don't require setting up a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
# Create pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6],
                   'Region':['North','South','East','West',
                            'North','South','East','West',
                            'North','South','East','West',
                            'North','South','East','West',
                            'Northwest','South West','Northwest','South West'
                            ]
                  })

# A method of indexing the regions per ID from 1 to n regions
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Region Idx'})
offset = df['Region Idx']*df['ID'].diff()
offset.loc[offset==0] = math.nan
offset = offset.ffill().fillna(0)
df['Region Idx'] = df['Region Idx'] - offset + 1

# Assuming your IDs are integers in ascending order 
# and you don't have any special cases with the number of regions per ID,
# this can be used for the rolling region selection per ID
df['Max Region'] = df[['ID','Region Idx']].groupby('ID').transform('max')
df['Selected Region Idx'] = (df['ID']-1) % df['Max Region'] + 1

# Final result
result = df.loc[df['Region Idx']==df['Selected Region Idx'],['ID','Region']]
```

Comment: Good solution but I do have IDs with a different number of regions.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought using [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
id_idx = df.groupby('ID').ngroup().drop_duplicates().index
region_idx = df.groupby('Region').ngroup().drop_duplicates().index
out = pd.DataFrame()
out['ID'], out['Region'] = df.loc[id_idx, 'ID'].values, df.loc[region_idx, 'Region'].values

print(out)

   ID      Region
0   1       North
1   2       South
2   3        East
3   4        West
4   5   Northwest
5   6  South West
```